# Gauge invariance of Landau-Ginsburg model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauge

Free energy density for Landau-Ginsburg model is given by:
$$
F=\frac{1}{2\mu}(\vec\nabla \times \vec A)^2+|(\vec\nabla-ie\vec A)\phi|^2+a(T-T_c)|\phi|^2+\lambda|\phi|^4
$$
And I was trying to show that it is gauge invariant under:
$\vec A \rightarrow\vec A'=\vec A+\frac{1}{e}\vec\nabla \Lambda \,\ $ and $\,\ \phi \rightarrow \phi'=e^{i\Lambda}\phi $. I managed to show that for  $\,\ \phi\,\ $ and $\,\ \vec\nabla \times \vec A \,\ $ by direct substitution. But then
$$
|(\vec\nabla-ie\vec A')\phi'|=|(\vec\nabla-ie(\vec A+\frac{1}{e}\vec\nabla \Lambda)||\phi'|=|(\vec\nabla-ie\vec A -i\vec\nabla \Lambda)||\phi|
$$

So it looks as if there is $+i\vec\nabla \Lambda$ missing. Is there any mistake in that derivation?

Comment: $|D\phi|\neq|D|\,|\phi|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to differentiate the exponent in the product:
$(\vec\nabla-ie\vec A')\phi'=(\vec\nabla-ie(\vec A+\frac{1}{e}\vec\nabla \Lambda)(e^{i\Lambda} \phi)=e^{i\Lambda}(\vec\nabla-ie\vec A -i\vec\nabla \Lambda+i\vec\nabla\Lambda)\phi=e^{i\Lambda}(\vec\nabla-ie\vec A )\phi$